# null pointer exception string 2d array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, 2d

```
public String[][] fetchData()
{
    String[][] data = null;
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < 10){
        data[counter] = new String[] {"abc"};
        counter++;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Getting the error in this loop.
Please let me know where i am wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to allocate memory to data.

```
String[][] data = new String[ROW][COLUMN].
```

Read [this](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/arrays-2D-2.html)

Comment: Sweet handle! Where'd you get the pic? Is that the cover for the last book?

Comment: @Code-Guru Nope. This is the cover: http://www.tor.com/blogs/2012/05/michael-whelans-cover-for-a-memory-of-light-revealed

Comment: Sweet! I love it! Can't wait!

Comment: @Code-Guru I as well. I hope you read the first chapter. If not here is the link. Some spoilers at the end! http://www.tor.com/stories/2012/09/a-memory-of-light-chapter-1-qeastward-the-wind-blewq

Comment: I found the prologue, but not the first chapter. I'll have to find some time to read them both later.

Comment: Looks like I will have to get the prologue later. It's only available as an ebook.

Comment: Yeah I didn't read that too :( But fear not! This January I hope it begins! (and ends :() 
I hope you enjoy the first chapter. I know I did.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17456/discussion-between-code-guru-and-lews-therin)

Answer (score 2):

```
String[][] data = null;
```

==> you have a null pointer exception when you try to write in data

You might do

```
String[][] data = new String[10][];
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a NPE because you explicitly set `data` to `null`:

```
String[][] data = null;
```

You need to allocate the number of rows first:

```
String[][] data = new String[][NUMBER_OF_ROWS];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data[counter] = new String[] {"abc"};
```

Here you are putting "abc" to array, but why you're using array if it has only one cell?

```
data[counter] = new String("sample string");
```

would be enough. And ofc you need also to declare "data" as one-dimensional array.